# What achievements are impossible without DLC purchases?

Tags: achievements, beautiful-katamari

What *Beautiful Katamari* achievements are impossible without purchasing any DLC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [achievements guide](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=42050) at xbox360achievements.org shows only 3 that require DLC:

- All Cousins (80 G)
- All Presents (80 G)
- Astronomic Katamari (90 G)

Note that these are the only three achievements that say "Download stages ..." in their description, and they add up to the 250 that's standard for DLC.